# Generating grid in a box

Tags: tcolorbox, grids

I'm using the following preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newtcolorbox{learng}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colframe=titlegrammar,
  colback=titlegrammar!03,
  overlay unbroken and first={
    \node[
      draw=titlegrammar,
      fill=titlegrammar,
      rotate=270,
      anchor=north west,
      text=white,
      font=\bfseries
    ]
    at (frame.north west)
    {LEARN THIS!};
  }
}

\definecolor{titlegrammar}{RGB}{255,128,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{learng}
text goes here
\end{learng}

\end{document}
```

This generates a similar box:

[image]

If you look closely to the picture, you'll see some kind of grid yielded. I'd like to replicate that result. Is it possible?

---

After having my question answered, I made some modifications and the result is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `underlay={...}` option with `\fill[...]` and a `\filldraw` for the grid. I have used some opacity value to reduce the intensity of the colour, but this depends on personal views, of course.

Since `tcolorbox` uses Ti*k*Z in the background, basically all `TikZ` operations are possible.

The white lines are exaggerated here on purpose for demonstration only!

Basically, only the `colframe` colour needs to be specified, all other values are using `tcbcol@frame` then.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{titlegrammar}{RGB}{255,128,0}
\newtcolorbox{learng}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colframe=titlegrammar,
  colback=tcbcol@frame!03,
  overlay unbroken and first={
    \node[
      draw=tcbcol@frame,
      fill=tcbcol@frame,
      rotate=270,
      anchor=north west,
      text=white,
      font=\bfseries
    ]
    at (frame.north west)
    {LEARN THIS!};
  },
  underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[tcbcol@frame,opacity=0.4] (interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
      \filldraw[help lines,step=5mm,line width=2pt,white,shift={(interior.north west)}]
      (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{learng}
\blindtext
\end{learng}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, it's getting closer to what I want. I saw again the picture and I realised that the lines of the grids are white and the background is orange, can you yield that?

Comment: @Ustanak: See the update (exaggerated ;-))