# Grid a single page

Tags: grids

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292877/generating-grid-in-a-box), I'd like to grid a single page using the grid style provided in the link. (Note that I don't want to grid the whole pages, just the one I want to.)

Comment: I've adjusted the answer some time ago, please have look if this is what you desired!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I thought I'd done this before. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses the `background` package to draw basically the same grid as in the linked question.

In order to switch on or off use `opacity=1` or `opacity=0` and `backgroundsetup` (in conjunction with a `\clearpage`)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0]{background}

\definecolor{titlegrammar}{RGB}{255,128,0}



\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{position={0,0},opacity=0.3,placement=bottom,angle=0,scale=1,contents={\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[titlegrammar] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \filldraw[help lines,step=5mm,line width=1pt,white]      (0cm,0cm) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\BgThispage
\blindtext[2]
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{opacity=0}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Controlling the different `opacity=` values for `\fill` and `\filldraw` they can be wrapped in `scope` environment and using the `[transparency group]` option. This allows specifying separate values.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0]{background}

\definecolor{titlegrammar}{RGB}{255,128,0}



\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{position={0,0},opacity=0.1,placement=bottom,angle=0,scale=1,contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.3]
      \fill[titlegrammar] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      \begin{scope}[transparency group]
      \filldraw[opacity=0.6,help lines,step=5mm,line width=1pt,white]      (0cm,0cm) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\BgThispage
\blindtext[2]
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{opacity=0}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a thing: in the link provided, you can see that the lines are actually white and the squares are orange. I'd like to flip the colors of your result. Can you do it?

Comment: @Ustanak: See the update -- I forgot that you preferred the reversal ;-) Handle the `opacity` option with care and provide it to `\backgroundsetup` only, not to `\fill` etc.

Comment: Thank you again. I see that `opacity` controls both `\filldraw` and `\fill`, can we control them separately? Because I'm modifying the opacity of `\fill` but I want to control the opacity of `\filldraw` separately.

Comment: @Ustanak: It might be possible, but `background` is effectively a `tikz` package, i.e. it uses the same controls as `\filldraw` etc. Perhaps with `layers`, but that needs some work to do.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you can pull it off!

Comment: @Ustanak: Sorry, I forgot about this question -- I've added a solution about the several `opacity` parameters -- use `\begin{scope}[transparency group]...\end{scope}`